# How to check if string contains a string in string array

Tags: c#, linq

**edit:** the order might change as you can see in the below example, both string have same name but  different order....

How would you go after checking to see if the both string array match?

the below code returns true but in a reality its should return false since I have extra string array in the `_check`

what i am trying to achieve is to check to see if both string array have same number of strings.

```
string _exists  = "Adults,Men,Women,Boys";
string  _check = "Men,Women,Boys,Adults,fail";

if (_exists.All(s => _check.Contains(s))) //tried Equal 
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: _Same number_ of strings? I assume you mean the _same strings_ instead?! If the order doesn't matter, does it matter how often a string occurs(f.e. the first contains "Men" two times, the second contains it only one time? Does the case matter? Is it possible that a string contains a comma?

Comment: @Tim, same number of strings meaning if _exists have 5 string (one, two,three....) then _check should also have 5 strings (two, one, three ...)  see the LB answer and i think i got what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string _exists  = "Adults,Men,Women,Boys";
string  _check = "Men,Women,Boys,Adults,fail";

bool b = _exists.Split(',').OrderBy(s=>s)
                .SequenceEqual(_check.Split(',').OrderBy(s=>s));
```

Comment: very good!, the order by helps clear up ambiguities caused with duplicate string tokens.

Comment: 1+ this is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Those are not array of strings, but two strings.
So, you actually need to split them into substrings before checking for the content equality.

You can do in this way:

```
string _exists = "Adults,Men,Women,Boys";
string _check = "Men,Women,Boys,Adults,fail";

var checks = _check.Split(',');
var exists = _exists.Split(',');

bool stringsEqual = checks.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(exists.OrderBy(x => x));
```

To speed up a bit some special cases, you could check for length before calling the LINQ code (avoiding the two OrderBy's in case of different lengths). Furthermore, to save memory, you could use in-place sort on the splits arrays, i.e. :

```
string _exists = "Adults,Men,Women,Boys";
string _check = "Men,Women,Boys,Adults,fail";

var checks = _check.Split(',');
var exists = _exists.Split(',');

if(checks.Length != exists.Length)
    return false;

Array.Sort(checks);
Array.Sort(exists);

if (checks.SequenceEqual(exists))
    return true;
return false;
```

Obviously these optimizations are useful only if your strings are really long, otherwise you can simply go with the LINQ one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return (_exists.Length == _check.Length);
```

That will check if the string arrays are the same length, but not necessarily the same values.

If you want to compare the arrays to see if they are exactly the same you will need to do the above first, then most likely sort the arrays into A-Z order, and compare each element

NOTE: This is unnecessary...

```
if (_exists.All(s => _check.Contains(s))) //tried Equal 
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

...you can do this, and it's more elegant...

```
return (_exists.All(s => _check.Contains(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if the number of substrings separated by a comma is the same, then use this.

```
public bool StringsHaveSameNumberOfSubstring(string _exists, string _check)
{
     return (_exists.Split(',').Length == _check.Split(',').Length);
}
```

This is what I understood from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Split the strings to make two list, and later compare them using Linq to Objects

```
string _exists  = "Adults,Men,Women,Boys";
string  _check = "Men,Women,Boys,Adults,fail";


List<string> exists = new List<string>(_exists.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
List<string> check = new List<string>(_check.Split(new char[] { ',' }));

foreach(string toCheck in check){
if(exists.Contains(toCheck)){
  //do things
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count strings try:

```
bool sameAmountOfStrings = _exists.Count(c => c.Equals(',')) == _check.Count(c => c.Equals(,));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to split the strings to get arrays and sort them

```
var ary1 = _existing.Split(',').Trim().OrderBy(x => x);
var ary2 = _check.Split(',').Trim().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Now you can use 'SequenceEquals' to compare the Enumerables

```
var result = ary1.SequenceEquals(ary2);
```

SeqenceEquals compares the position and value, so if you want to detect positional changes as well, remoce the OrderBy.